# New custom Create form does not auto complete “Owner“ field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, javascript, page-layout, custom-form

I have an Issue Tracking list , and I have created a custom Create form using SharePoint designer , as follow:-

The problem I am facing is that the owner field will not autocomplete the people & group s when the user start typing as  follow:-

While if I use the default Create form then I will get the auto complete feature. Can 
anyone advice what is the missing JavaScript and how I can add it ?
Thanks

Comment: Same issue I am seeing currently.